# ¿Cómo cambiar el fondo de un TextInputEditText desde el tema de la aplicación en Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, text

Tengo el siguiente código:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilRaceDecorationName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_x2"
                app:helperText="@string/race_nameField_textHelper"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cvImageBackground"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvImageBackground">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tieRaceFieldName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

La cuestión es que me gustaría cambiar `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` del elemento y ponerlo en el tema principal, el archivo llamada theme de la carpeta res/values.

He probado a mirar la documentación de google.io (https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#theming-text-fields), pero no termino de entender cómo hacer ese cambio.

Realmente lo único que quiero es que tenga un fondo transparente por defecto todo los textfield que haga en la aplicación.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, lo he conseguido.

La solución que he seguido ha sido:

en el style principal he añadido:
`<item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout</item>`

Y en el estilo que he creado he puesto:

```xml
<style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```